# Urban "fantasy" from the 80s - seniors in a condo community draining the life force of a young tenant couple

Tags: story-identification, vampire, urban-fantasy

This was an airport horror novel from the 80s with a "scientific" urban vampire twist.

- Starts out with a young couple searching for an apartment in an expensive city (NYC?) who find an amazing deal in an apartment complex.
- They get interviewed by the residents, who are much older, but look amazingly fit in general.
- They get accepted but, as soon as they move in, they are encouraged/nudged to take better care of their bodies, i.e. exercise and diet, drink less.  The wife is a bit reluctant at first, but a really good-looking older woman starts to flirt with her husband who has been working out, so she starts working out as well.
- One of the two (the wife, I think) starts being suspicious about what had happened to the previous, also much younger tenants.  Turns out one of the senior residents crash landed in South America decades previously.  The natives then nursed him back to health and youth, using human blood.  Since then he and his friends have been snaring young people to steal their blood.
- It may or may not have ended badly with the protagonist discovering, too late, captives in blood sucking machines.

Comment: It all ends badly — otherwise the description is very exact. I believe that the book came out around the time of one of the crazes for running.

Having said that, of course I can't think of the author or the title!